# VBA How do I replace the range with an array in SUMIF

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sumifs

I have a very simple SUMIF that looks something like this

```
lngth = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lngth

Range("L" & i & ":L" & lngth) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("Sheet2!A$2:A$1000"), Cells(i, 9), Range("H$2:H$1000"))
Next i
```

Unfortunately I no longer have the data range available. However the information is now presented in an array. How would I go about adjusting the SUMIF to use an array instead of the ranges?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Sumif is expecting range and if you pass array into it, you get type mismatch. I wrote this Sumif replacement you can try using.

Prerequisite for testing:
Range A1:B6 looking like this.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| d | 1 |
| a | 1 |

Code:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Range("A1:B6")
    Debug.Print mySumif(arr, "a", 1, 2)
End Sub

Function mySumif(ByVal arr As Variant, ByVal criteria As Variant, ByVal criteriaColNo As Integer, ByVal sumColNo As Integer) As Double
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, criteriaColNo) = criteria Then mySumif = mySumif + arr(i, sumColNo)
    Next i
End Function
```

Output:

```
3
```

How to use:

arr is the array, criteria is what you're looking for, criteriaColNo is the index of the column your criteria is in, sumColNo is the index of the column you want to sum.